# Erro ao gerar APK no Android android:exported

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tentando gerar o APK do android, mas ao tentar gera esse erro, já tenho no AndroidManifest.xml a tag android:exported="true", mas mesmo assim gera o erro.

```
Erro: android:exported precisa ser explicitamente especificado para o elemento <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity>. Aplicativos destinados ao Android 12 e superior precisam especificar um valor explícito para android:exportedquando o componente correspondente tiver um filtro de intenção definido
```

Comment: Para fornecer uma ajuda de mais qualidade, precisamos do máximo de contexto do seu problema. Nesse caso, incluir o conteúdo do seu arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml` seria ideal pois parece que o problema está nele.

Answer (score -3):

Você deve adicionar a linha `android:exported="true"` no seu `AndroidManifest.xml.`
Sua pergunta falta informações, compartilhe seus AndroidManifest completo, caso a alteração não resolva.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            ...
```